# Obtener la carpeta de index PHP

Tags: php

Buenas tardes compañeros, me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de obtener la carpeta de index en PHP estando en cualquier carpeta, hay alguna constante que al mencionarla pueda ponerla antes de la ruta de las demás carpetas para llegar a un fichero especifico?

Comment: Te saludo y doy la bienvenida, pudieras ser un poco más claro en tu pregunta por fas ya que cómo está ahorita no me queda muy clara saludos

Comment: Acabé de encontrar la forma, solo hice una constante 'RAIZ' en mi archivo index y le asigné la constante __DIR__ Muchas gracias.

Comment: Yo te aconsejo revisar la doc de la constante **__FILE__** y de funciones como **dirname()**. Saludos

Comment: También sería bueno que tomes en consideración utilizar un framework backend. Si comienzas a utilizarlo mientras aprendes PHP te ahorrará muchos dolores de cabeza y puede que te evite caer en algunas malas prácticas de programación por el lenguaje ser demasiado "permisivo". Un saludo

Comment: Otra cosa si normalmente encuentras la respuesta antes que cualquier otro usuario te suministré alguna por favor considera "autoresponder" tu pregunta de esta forma otros usuarios que lleguen aquí con una duda similar también pueden solucionar. Si es posible también valora el esfuerzo de aquellas personas que te dan una respuesta y que consideres aporten algo en la solución a tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Hiskie a que te refieres con framework backend? Me podrías citar algun ejemplo. Muchas gracias

Comment: @CarlosDanielZárateRamírez Si, Como no me gusta reinventar la rueda aquí tienes un concepto bastante preciso de [qué es un framework?](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framework). Por favor también chequea el siguiente enlace: [Frameworks de PHP](https://www.neoguias.com/mejores-frameworks-gratuitos-de-php/)

Comment: Cualquier duda comenta y con gusto ayudaré en lo que pueda. Trata de escribir "@usuario", por ejemplo, @Huskie de esa forma stackoverflow me notifica sobre tu comentario y así puedo responderlo. De otra forma ni me entero, de hecho me enteré por casualidad xD!

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el home de la pagina es con:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`, ejemplo:

```
include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]"/lib/functions.php";
```

> 'DOCUMENT_ROOT'
> El directorio raíz de documentos del servidor en el cual se está ejecutando el script actual, según está definida en el archivo de
> configuración del servidor.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).